# Non-lethal rodent deterrents that are safe and tolerable for cats

Tags: cats, rodents

We are currently facing an issue with **rodents, most likely mice or rats, having taken up residency in our flat roof**. The space itself is inaccessible for us or our cats, so they can't take care of this issue.

While we don't mind them per se and they do provide some entertainment for the cats with the noise they make in the night, they are apparently tearing up insulation while rearranging their residence and pose a fire hazard if they were to chew into electrical wiring, so we can't leave them there.

**Lethal options, as in poison, are out of scope here**, obviously due to the cats and local birds of prey potentially ingesting the victims, and we would very much like to avoid killing them.

**Live traps are not really a solution** either, as we live right next to a field, which comes with a truly massive population of rodents, so chances are we will mostly be trapping innocent bystanders.

I've been doing some research into **noisemaker devices** to scare them away, ultrasonic or audible spectrum, vibration, etc. The problem here is I couldn't find **reliable information if using these would stress out the cats**, manufacturers seem mostly concerned with the effect on the unwanted guests.

What I am looking for here would be:

- reliable information regarding noisemaker options being stressful for cats
- potential other non-lethal deterrents that are safe for cats

Comment: You may want to rethink your premise of "non-lethal"; Rodent fleas are generally blamed for the black plague and other diseases . I doubt their droppings result in anything good.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Appreciate the input, however short of tearing up and rebuilding the whole roof, there is nothing we can realistically do about droppings. Since this is a recurring issue in this neighborhood due to the nearby field, we will have to live with that. Poison isn't something we can use due to agricultural use of the field, and our own pets as well as endangered birds in the area. As far as traps go, there is no real benefit over live traps with those that kill, and there are too many rodents in the area to make them viable options.

Comment: By searchin on german websites I find again and again "close all holes they could come through (after be secure there is no mouse inside anymore)" and "use strong smells to scare them away". Smells like peppermint oil, terpentin and used cat litter ^^ How bad is your access to the roof? And do you know, how they come in? Because they need to go out for food right?

Comment: @Allerleirauh There is no access at all for us to the roof, it is a bungalow style flat roof from the 1960s. We are pretty sure they are accessing the roof through vent holes, emergency drainage holes or something of the sort. Closing all those holes up is probably going to be next to impossible, there are literally hundreds of them, some hidden behind outdoor paneling, etc. The smell suggestion might work though, since we could drill into the ceiling in a few spots and stick tubing through into the internal roof structure to disperse something.

Comment: Closing not in any case means fully close. Imagine metal mesh wire or similar... Maybe?

Comment: I had success with an electronic shock trap (for both mice and rats, Rat Zapper for example). The rats were typically in and on the roof but we were able to get them with the trap placed on the ground along an external wall. We don't have cats, but our dogs were not able to access the trap/bait and we did not have to worry about poison.

Comment: I think that the question is not answerable at all, not only on this site. All of the following are rodents: mice, rats, rabbits, capybaras, as well as many others. The solution is different for each of them. Finding an unusual solution for an unknown problem is deemed to bring to the table potential disasters. The only proper solution is to deal with the problem professionally. There are only 2 ways: you destroy your house in a controlled way to solve the problem, or those critters will eat through your house in the most random fashion. Saving some lives should only be a side effect.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about pets. It is about a problem that needs to be solved professionally. If not solved professionally, it can lead to disasters (mechanical, health-related etc.)

Comment: I disagree that it's not about pets; the question isn't about how to control the rodents, but how to do so *in a cat-safe manner,* which is relevant to this stack.

Answer (score -1):

I am pleased that you do not want to use poison. Thank you for this! I have found that daily application of peppermint oil deters rats as they have a very sensitive sense of smell. It will not hurt them. They simply do not like the smell. The key is this--it's a lot of work!! as you must apply the oil profusely morning and night, but it works. I did this for years until I adopted a cat, then he took care of the rats!!

Comment: Be aware, that peppermint may be dangerous for cats! They absorb things even through their paw's skin, so peppermint oil at surfaces where the cat walks are a bad idea...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).